# Different results from Dijkstra algorithms

Tags: graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I am working from Programming Game AI by Example book. Look at this image, the result on the left is the author's, the one on the right is mine. Green is source and red is target. Dijkstra is applied, and you can see the shortest path but also the other paths that were searched. How come my image is different, what could this mean?

[image]

Comment: How do you possibly expect anyone to answer this question if you haven't shown your code?

Comment: Well I don't expect someone to spend a day on the code I guess.

Comment: People will spend precisely zero seconds on the images.

Comment: You can take my advice, or ignore it.  But what you will find is that people will most likely vote to close this as "not a real question".

Comment: At a very quick glance it looks like they weight diagonal walks heavier then vertical or horizontal ones. Yours looks like it weighs going n,s,w,e,ne,nw,se,sw all the same.

Comment: @pokoko: Please read the FAQ.  You need to ask a question with a specific, objective answer, not opinions...

Comment: @pokoko: Actually, I am drunk.  Nevertheless, this is not a suitable question for SO.

Comment: @pokoko222 Honestly, I find Oli to be one of the most insightful and helpful guys on this site. This place really requires something concrete to go off of. We can only guess what the cause is by looking at your question - we need something solid; something exact; we need to see the code generating your graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a very quick glance it looks like they weight diagonal walks heavier then vertical or horizontal ones. Yours looks like it weighs going n,s,w,e,ne,nw,se,sw all the same. Hence you go diagonal when they went horizontal or vertical.

Comment: Hmm, weights are actually computed as distance. Maybe even one pixel difference might make a difference. It probably is this kind of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you just used different tiebreakers when selecting the next square. From what I see you searched the same squares in the same amount of time, but in the part where you arbitrarily pick the next square to search, you chose differently.